# Adding Delay/wait-time in a VSTS web test loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, performance-testing, load-testing

We are trying to simulate a scenario something as below with VSTS load test

1. User logs in
2. User performs few actions
3. User starts editing a document (there are autosave calls happening at every 5 seconds)

To simulate 3rd step we added a counting loop and added rest call for autosave. We are not able to figure out a way of introducing a delay of 5 seconds in loop.

We cant break the above flow into multiple webtests as we need to share few context variables across the requests in webtest.

Think times also won't help us as in our specific case we need delay/wait only between calling autosave endpoint and not between step 1 and 2.

Thanks in Advance!

--- Update 
Look at AdrianHHH comments on Answer of Ivan Kožul. 
This is almost on same lines of [Insert 120 second wait in Visual studio Webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346254/insert-120-second-wait-in-visual-studio-webtest/47346920#47346920)

Comment: You want your code to delay (or freeze) for 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I want a delay between two requests in VSTS load test.

Comment: Please explain how you are doing step-3? If you have a web-test loop then put a think time on the request in that loop. You may also want a think time on the last request in step-2 as think times are done after the request.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:`Task.Delay` when you want a logical delay without blocking the current thread. Which is probably exactly what you need.

Check the documentation: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)

Comment: This may work in some code, but not in a Visual Studio web test. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346254/insert-120-second-wait-in-visual-studio-webtest/47346920#47346920

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for, not sure how I missed that question before posting this on almost the same lines! While updating "local.testsetting" to allow think times, there are two options 1. "run tests using local computer or a test controller" 2. "Run tests using Visual Studio Team services". "Web test" setting is only available when option 1 is selected. This means when we add this web test to load test and run in VS cloud, these request specific think times will be ignored? Could you please clarify.

Comment: @Dileep17 The "Web test" part of the ".testsettings" file only applies to standalone web tests. When a web test is run as part of a ".loadtest" then the properties in the "Run settings" apply. See item (2) of the link above. See also the discussion of ".testsettings" files in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984628/upload-a-file-through-a-microsoft-webtest/40992355#40992355 (the final two paragraphs are particularly relevant). If you find answers in other questions helpful then please consider voting them, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote